# "Unexpected type required class found type parameter Attack"

Tags: java, generics, copy-constructor, type-parameter

this is my code (trying to write a copy constructor for my class):

```
public class ArgumentTree<GameArgument, Attack> extends DelegateTree<GameArgument, Attack>
{
    public ArgumentTree()
    {super();}

    public ArgumentTree(ArgumentTree<GameArgument, Attack> sourceTree)
    {
        super();
        Attack atck = new Attack(); // I get the Error here
        more code....
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
unexpected type  
 required: class  
 found:   type parameter Attack
```

just to clarify: I don't want to make the code generic. I already know that the types I will use will be only GameArgument and Attack. Also, Attack has its own proper default constructor.

Comment: Your code *is* generic, whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using actual class names as type variables. This doesn't make sense. Maybe you want something like

```
public class ArgumentTree extends DelegateTree<GameArgument, Attack>
```